# Object closely follows other object being moved

Tags: 3d-view

When I import object B in my scene, It appears at origin 0, near object **A** (which is keyframed). I cannot seem to move **A** away from **B** without **B** loosely following... What is the relationship at work here? How can I move object **A** without **B** being affected?

Comment: do you have proportional editing on ?

Comment: Yes I do. Please make it an answer so I can upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving, rotating or scaling  an object while the Proportional editing is on will propagate the effect to neighbors objects "or vertices in edit mode" .
you can toggle proportional editing ON and OFF in the 3D viewport from the icon or using the shortcut <kbd>O</kbd>

[image]